# Can you Help me to write optimize sql query?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

My query too much time to execute for fetching data.

```
SELECT `app`.*, `pat`.`title`, `email_address`, `bad_debtor`, `county`, `date_of_birth`, `dentist_id`, `doctor_id`, `ethnicity`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `pat`.`mobile_phone`, `pat`.`prevent_appointment_booking`, `pat`.`use_email`, `pat`.`use_sms`, `pat`.`recall_method`, `pat`.`status`, `pat`.`pat_id`, `pat`.`active` FROM `patients` `pat` LEFT JOIN `appoiment` `app` ON `pat`.`id` = `app`.`patient_id` WHERE (date(app.start_time) > date(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY) and `app`.`state` IN ('Completed') and `app`.`patient_id` is not NULL GROUP BY `pat`.`id`
```

This part

```
WHERE (date(app.start_time) > date(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY) and `app`.`state` IN ('Completed') and `app`.`patient_id` is not NULL
```

the problem is in where clause which takes too much time.
help me to optimize query.

Comment: What format is `app.start_time`?

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write. Add some line-breaks, and indentation.

Comment: Which dbms are you using

Comment: Show us table and index definitions. And the explain/execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace app. * with the correct column you need

Comment: problem in where clause

Comment: @ZAINULABIDEEN152 You have to make sure which column is used as the index and primary key. There's no problem with where clause. specifying the required column is better than using *

Comment: We can't tell if the WHERE clause is fine or not since the question lacks information. However, `select *` is discouraged mainly because applications using it might break if a column later is added to the table. (And, performance wise, big columns might add _some_ transfer time - but far from the difference a missing index makes.)